# Shuffle elements when they are removed using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a structure like so:

```
<ul>
<li>
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
</li>
<li>
<span>4</span>
<span>5</span>
<span>6</span>
<span>7</span>
<span>8</span>
</li>
<li>
<span>9</span>
<span>10</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

I need to reorganise to:

```
<ul>
<li>
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
<span>4</span>
<span>5</span>
</li>
<li>
<span>6</span>
<span>7</span>
<span>8</span>
<span>9</span>
<span>10</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: See http://www.elated.com/articles/jquery-removing-replacing-moving-elements/

Comment: Where's the code that does the removal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var spans = $('span').toArray();
$('li').each(function(i, li) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (spans.length == 0) break;
        $(spans.shift()).appendTo(li);
    }
    if ($(li).find('span').length === 0) {
        $(li).remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var spans = $('span');
var ul = $('ul').html(''); //UL Empty
var li = $('<li>').appendTo(ul);

$.each(spans, function(ind, ele){
    if (ind == 5)
        li = $('<li>').appendTo(ul);
    li.append( ele );
});
```

this way you avoid a for loop within each functions